# Mobile media query overrided by desktop values?

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, center

So I have a page with a long list of classes, and below each title, there is an icon (image) stating what type of class it is. On the desktop, I have it set to display center under the title. On mobile, I wish to do the same thing. However, when I align it center in mobile using margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto, it stays on the side. If I push it over using margin-left: 40px, it'll move but on the desktop, it also pushes over. If I go to the desktop media query and make the margin-left: 0, it changes the margin to 0 for both desktop and mobile.

Here's the css:

```
.classicons1 {
    margin-left: 45%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 10%;
    display: inline;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 880px) {
.classicons1 {
    width: 7%;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0;
}
}
```

Every other element in the media querys work, except this one and any new elements I create. When I open it up in inspect mode on Chrome, I can see that the mobile elements are crossed out, being overrided by the desktop elements.

Comment: first the use of inline isn't approprite when setting width

Answer (score 0):

What I could find wrong with your CSS is the following:

1. Your media query is wrong, if you want to make it for mobile you should use:

   `@media (max-width: 768px) {/*css code here*/}`
2. The best way I have found to center things to their parents width is the following:

   `margin: 0 auto; display: table/block;`
3. Finally, if you want to test if your elements are being overridden in any respect, there are two ways to avoid this. Either put your CSS inline with html using `style` attribute OR use the following code:

   `property: property-value !important` the `!important` gives it priority, try not to use it as your solution though and only use `!important` as a debugging method. It should be considered a last resort.

*Note: If you are seeing code being crossed out in chrome using inspect-element (debug console) you are most likely overriding your CSS using other attributes, whether that be from inline html CSS, or from other classes that may be affecting the class you are trying to edit. Keep this in mind when debugging your code.